# Finding the largest set of points of limited diameter (2)

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, cg.comp-geom

> **Problem:** Given a set of points $S = \{(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2),\cdots,(x_n, y_n)\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and a distance threshold $\tau$, find a subset of $S$ such that (1) the Euclidean distance between any two points of the subset is not greater than $\tau$, and (2) the subset is maximum.

In a related [post](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3512/finding-the-largest-set-of-points-of-limited-diameter), Eppstein mentions that the problem can be solved in $O(n^3\log n)$. I wonder

- Is there any improvement of the complexity since then?
- If we instead enumerate the maximal ones, can it be in PTIME?